# Spring data JPA : How to organize repositories and service layer for multiple datasources containing same entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity *EntityA* that is present in multiple datasources, *datasourceA* and *datasourceB*. Basically, same table but different content exists in both databases.

How should I organize my spring boot application in this scenario? Currently I have the following :

- 1 entity class
- 2 Repositories, one for each datasource. I have a config file that indicate the datasource that a repository should use.
- 1 service class which, based on a given argument, queries one of the repositories.

The problem with this is that, in my real program, I have 6 entities that are all shared among 6 datasources, which leads me to have 32 repositories, one for each entity and for each datasource. Also my code for choosing the right repository to use in the service class gets quite long.

Is this the best way to approach the problem or is there a way to better organize this / limit the number of repositories needed? Spring boot is using hibernate in my application.

Comment: I'm wondering why do you have multiple repositories based on data sources? Are they possible to be shared together?

Comment: Were these different datasources created to manage different environment like, local, dev, prod etc. ? Or, Are they totally different datasources but they are sharing same entity in their in own schema?

Comment: @AlperDerya They represent different domains in the application. The datasources contain some metrics about servers (like load, delay, ...), and the metrics for each server are taken every few seconds and stored in a different database. The metrics in itself are exactly of the same type. I'm not sure if this is a good architecture but it's out of my control

Comment: @HungNguyenDuy I don't know, I'm trying to assign a datasource to a repository dynamically but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure but this may have some information you need:
https://javatodev.com/multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-data-jpa/

Comment: @HungNguyenDuy Thank you! It is actually really similar to the implementation I have at the moment. But this guide does also create one repository for each datasource. I think what I'm asking might not be possible and I'll try to implement the answer I got below

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to create multiple instance of repository, each inject with its corresponding EntityManager (which represents a datasource), as long as you are not mixing the entities from different EMs.  What I don't know yet is how you could manually create repository :P  wish this is a starting point to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these duplicate entities will be always updated at same time for each data source then you can maintain only one entity as system wide. Otherwise, you need to create unique entities for each data source. You already stated that you configured datasources for repository management. You can also centralized the usage of repositories by inheritance. Like;

```
public interface BaseLoadRepository extends CrudRepository<LoadEntity, Long>

public interface DataSource1LoadRepo extends BaseLoadRepository

public interface DataSource2LoadRepo extends BaseLoadRepository
```

It gives you opportunity to add new method independently for each datasource. This approach also can be used for entites.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it shouldn't be possible for an interface to implement another interface no?

Comment: You are right. It would be "extends". I just edited the answer. Does the approach make sense?

Comment: I think so, I will try implementing it and update on how it went

Comment: It worked nicely and helped clean the mess in some files, thanks

Comment: Your welcome, I am happy to hear that.